# How to override/replace/disable IIS client certificate validation

Tags: ssl, iis, https, client-certificates

I have some applications that use *pinned* client certificates as credentials to access WCF services, and am in the process of moving some of this functionality into ASP.NET WebAPI and would like to continue accepting pinned certificates, but over mutual TLS instead of as a WCF service credential.

..However, I'm getting 403's back from IIS when I try to submit requests, and based on IIS failed request tracing, the reason is: *A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.*

This is not wrong. The cert in question is self-signed and absolutely *not* trusted for any reason except that it's been explicitly tied to an identity in the software. And..I want IIS to accept it so we can get to the application to decide how to proceed. My code is never run, however, because the cert is already rejected.

Is it possible to force IIS to pass the cert through, the way a WCF service would, without affecting other websites or processes running on the server?

Comment: The certificate must be trusted in the system for IIS to allow it on the app using WCF. That makes me believe you are trying to implement the ASP.NET app in a separate system, otherwise it would already be trusted in the system. What do you mean you don't want to affect the other websites or processes running on the server? In other words what have you tried to be concerned about this?

Comment: WCF doesn't have any particular certificate requirements. I can add any cert in the world as a credential on my client, call a service, and see the cert on the other side. All of these are pinned certs with absolutely no chain of trust to vouch for them.

As far as concerns, I came across a few StackOverflow posts I ended up not referencing that suggest a variety of registry hacks and/or changes to http.sys. If it came to that, I think I'd rather drop X.509 authentication entirely (and for the moment, for this project, have.)

Comment: I would not recommend lowering the security level on the server to allow *any* self signed cert. It may not be an option, but have you tried adding the certs to the Trusted Cert Store in mmc?

Comment: I agree. I definitely don't want to change anything at the server level - I have a single route, in a single website, that needs to be able to accept a client certificate such that the client can prove they know the private key without disclosing it. Mutual TLS is the natural choice for this, and I have an unrelated Azure Function doing so, but IIS is requiring the certs to validate. ..Adding the public key to the Trusted People store is an interesting idea, and may work for my immediate problem, but I do still need to be able to handle this programmatically.

Comment: So, I expected adding it to the Trusted People store would count, but it looks like no. Adding it to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities _does_ count, but holy crap no.

Comment: Can you trust a DIFFERENT cert as a Trusted Root Authority, then request the clients to create new cert requests that you would process using the new trusted cert authority. In other words you would only trust those certs that you issue yourself.

Comment: Honestly, yes, we could. That's the essence of PKI, and it might make sense for a future evolution of this project. Moving to a different type of proof entirely might as well. I'm also curious how Azure AppService handles this, since Azure Functions allow certs to pass through to the application the way I want. In any case, I think there's value in leaving the question open in case there _is_ a way to do this in IIS while exploring other avenues.

Comment: @WilliamScalf: Have you ever found a solution to the problem? We're facing the same issue.

Comment: @WilliamScalf Any solution for this? Facing same issue...

Comment: @D.R. - Hey, I just saw these comments. So, not specifically, no. I ended up keeping it as a WCF service hosted in the site IIRC, though you can also offload the certificate negotiation to a proxy (like nginx) that gives you more control, which I think we also did for a different thing. (Though it's been a while now.)

Comment: @osmankatib - see previous comment